# Can not send data from c#(controller) to javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, post

I have this code on my JavaScript file:

```
temp="string";
var myJson = JSON.stringify(temp);
    $.ajax(
        {
            url: '/MemoryGame/updateStatus',
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            data: myJson,
            success: function (response) {
                alert("success");
                if (response == 'Okay') {
                    checkStatus(temp.myID);
                }
               else {
                    ConnectionChanged();
                }
            },
            error: function (errorThrown) {
                console.log(errorThrown);
                ConnectionChanged();
            }
        });
```

And this controller:

```
[HttpPost]
        public string updateStatus(string updatedJson)
        {

            var Player = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GameDataClass>(updatedJson);
            var Opponent = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GameDataClass>(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(System.IO.Path.Combine(_env.WebRootPath, Player.OpponentID + ".json"))); 
... }
```

I tried to change  $.ajax to  $.post method, also changed

> public string updateStatus

to

> public JsonResult updatedStatus

But neither of this didn't work. myJson on javascript contain data but when it reaches controller updatedJson is empty. I've never had this kind of experience so I'm using this code from another project and it works very well there. So can somebody suggest me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: is this an MVC or WEBAPI controller?

Comment: @developer MVC controller

Comment: Does it go to the success block or error? What do you return from `updateStatus`? What values do you get in `response` and `errorThrown`?

Comment: @adiga oh i forgot to wrote. the myJson on javascript is not empty, it has data, but when it reaches controller updateJson is empty

Comment: Try with `data: { updatedJson:  myJson }`

Comment: @adiga i tried it several times, it doesn't change anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    temp="string";
    // (0)
    var myJson = JSON.stringify(temp);
    $.ajax(
        {
            url: '/MemoryGame/updateStatus?updatedJson=' + temp, // (1)
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            data: '',   // (2)
            success: function (response) {
                alert("success");
                if (response == 'Okay') {
                    checkStatus(response.myID);
                }
               else {
                    ConnectionChanged();
                }
            },
            error: function (errorThrown) {
                ConnectionChanged();
            }
        });
```

Or if this does not have to be passed as a parameter, then do the following:
(0)  var formData = new FormData(); formData.append('updatedJson', temp);
(1)  url: '/MemoryGame/updateStatus',
(2)  data: formData,

Answer (score 0):

[$.ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) is a fonction from the jQuery library, does your project include it ?

You can also check the Javascript console of your browser to see if it contains errors. On Firefox and Chrome you can access it by pressing F12.